# How to put button to the botton left in the div

Tags: html, css, sass, bootstrap-4

Suppose to have a div with a button, I want put this button on the bottom left:

```
----------------------------


button
---------------------------
```

this is my html:

```html
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <button type="button" label="Cancella Stazioni selezionate" style="margin-top:10%"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using flexbox

**`align-self:flex-end`**

```css
.col-md-12 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

button {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="col-md-12 d-flex">
    <button type="button" label="Cancella Stazioni selezionate">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

or **`align-items:flex-end`**

```css
.col-md-12 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="col-md-12 d-flex">
    <button type="button" label="Cancella Stazioni selezionate">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap 4 [`mt-auto`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/spacing/#notation) class like so:

- **m** - sets margin
- **t** - sets margin-top or padding-top
- **auto** - sets margin to auto

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #E6E2EB;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="wrapper d-flex">
  <div class="mt-auto p-2">
    <button type="button" label="Cancella Stazioni selezionate">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do that using a simple CSS trick: `position`.

```css
.container
{
   
   border: 1px dashed grey;
   height: 10em;
   background-color: #def;
   position: relative;
}

button
{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;

}
```

```html
<div class="col-12">
 <div class="col-md-12 container">
   <button type="button" label="Cancella Stazioni selezionate">Button 1</button>
   
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<button class="myclass">
  CLick
</button>

.myclass{
  position: fixed; 
  left: 0px; 
  background-color: green; 
  bottom: 0px
}
```

Checkout this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4uvf6Lge/